How to ensure Chrome extensions only have access to specific sites
I wish to restrict a specific chrome extension to have access to only Youtube. I have inputted the below in that extension's settings.

However, I still seem to be able to manually enable the extension for other sites by clicking on the extension and then this Reload button?

Furthermore, I've noticed the extension is enabled anyway on some sites that aren't youtube (including, say superuser.com).
Is the whitelist feature of Chrome faulty? Any way I can resolve this?

You can easily disable an extension, and then enable it only when needed. That way, you're not relying on the extension for privacy on other sites.

You may check Chrome extension called "Extension Manager", which will allow you disable\enable extensions only on specific websites without having to worry that extensions are tracking you while you are surfing on the Internet.
